# gnuplot: multi-line x-labels are cropped

Tags: gnuplot

In gnuplot, I want an xlabel that spans 2 lines. However, the label is currently cropped when I execute the script below. How do I resolve this?

data.txt

```
"my label A\nmy label B" 20
```

data.plt

```
set term postscript eps enhanced color font "Helvetica,20"
set output "data.eps"
set style data histogram
set style histogram gap 1
plot "data.txt" u 2:xticlabels(1)
```

[image]

Comment: You can create pdf output directly by using the `pdfcairo` terminal...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a bit dirty solution would be to use `bmargin` to specify the bottom margin manually and then play with the offsets of the labels (other side-effect of these multiline tics is that they will overlap with the axis label should the latter be long enough).

So the command would be

```
set bmargin 6
```

Here, the default units are character heights. Alternatively, one can also specify for example

```
set bmargin at screen 0.1
```

in order to set the bottom margin at 10% of the entire figure.